# Mouse jiggler for keeping multiple tabs / windows active

Tags: mouse, input-devices

I have a couple of annoying apps and webpages that automatically kick you out if they sense that you are idle.  I am trying to bypass this feature by using a [mouse jiggler](https://mousejiggler.org/).  However, the "jiggle stride" cannot be customized so it's hard to have the jiggler jiggle multiple windows & chrome tabs at the same time.

Is there a chrome extension that allows me to simulate mouse movement on multiple tabs?
Or is there any other program that will allow me to have customizable jiggle stride to jiggle multiple windows at once?

Answer (score 1):

[Mouse Move](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/move-mouse/9nq4ql59xlbf?activetab=pivot:overviewtab#) seems like a more customizable and powerful alternative to mouse jiggler which allows you to set stride distance and direction

Comment: Thanks for posting what you found! Do you have a non-MS link for the application you are recommending that you can add to your answer?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I haven't personally tested, but [xdotool](https://superuser.com/questions/126757/how-can-i-move-the-mouse-pointer-on-linux-without-actually-moving-the-mouse) and [python3-autopilot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986286/simulate-mouse-movement-in-ubuntu) seems promising

Comment: Thanks Rufus.  Those look interesting too.  Is Mouse Move only available from the MS store, or is it available directly from the developer as well?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) (FREE) or [PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849522/how-to-perform-keystroke-inside-powershell) (built in to Windows) to cycle between windows/tabs (using keyboard shortcuts/mouse movement and clicks) and send mouse/keystrokes to the focused window.